# Как сделать просвет сквозь div что бы показывало img?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так что бы div просвечивался через другой div и было видно img

Answer (score 0):

Еси я правильно вас понял, нужно изменить свойство `opacity` у контейнера на десятичное число: 0 – полностью невидимый, 1 – непрозрачный. Например, так;

```
.container {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Ну не совсем я пытаюсь сделать редактирование фото и мне нужно что бы один фон всё затемнил а второй был прозрачным через этот фон, поймете точнее на сайте VK редактирование фото где нужно выбрать область или на FaceBook